# HornetQ Concurrent Session Usage in EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly-8, hornetq

I am using Wildfly-8.2.0 and have an EJB like:

```
@Singleton
public class MySingleton {
  @Inject JMSContext jmsCtx;

  public void addMessageToQueue(...) { ... }
}
```

And am seeing the error:
`Invalid concurrent session usage. Sessions are not supposed to be used by more than one thread concurrently` frequently in the logs from the addMessageToQueue method.

Since this is a singleton EJB, container managed concurrency with default @Lock(WRITE) applies. I do not see how this error could be possible.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in WildFly 8.x https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3338. Consider migrating to WildFly 9 (which is in beta) or using CDI `Instance` interface as suggested in `WFLY-3338`.

```
@Inject
private Instance<JMSContext> context;

public void sendMessage(String text, boolean useTopic) {
    final Destination destination = useTopic ? topic : queue;
    context.get().createProducer().send(destination, text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, that is why that single session is used for sending request and getting response through listener. Create two separate sessions for each task will helps you.